# Showing that the points $A, \ B, \ 4B-3A$ are collinear

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm forgetting something basic on vectors here.

Say you have three points given by the position vectors $\vec a, \ \vec b, \ 4\vec b - 3\vec a$, how do you show that these points are collinear?

If we say that $\vec a = \vec{OA}$, $\vec b = \vec{OB}$, and $4\vec b - 3\vec a = \vec{OC}$ such that the points $A, B, C$ represent the vectors respectively, I think it would suffice to show that $\vec{AB} || \vec {BC}$ but I'm missing something.

Can someone push me along?

Comment: $P$ lies on line $AB$ if there exists $t\in\mathbb R$ such that: $P=A+t(B-A)$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca - I forgot to elaborate on that angle. What I've tried is saying that $B = A + \vec{AB}$ and $4B-3A = B + \vec{BC}$ so that $$4(B-A) = \vec{AB} + \vec{BC}$$ but I don't see how to complete it, or if this leads the right way.

Comment: $4\vec b-3\vec a=\vec a + 4 (\vec b-\vec a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract $\vec a$ from all vectors (i.e. translate the three points) and you get $\vec 0,\vec b-\vec a,3(\vec b-\vec a)$.

Comment: Very smooth. However, I did finish my own calculation. Maybe you can verify it? We see that $$4\vec b - 3\vec a = \vec a + \vec{AC}$$ and $$\vec b = \vec a + \vec{AB}$$ Then inserting the second into the first: $$4(\vec a + \vec{AB}) - 3\vec a = \vec a + \vec{AC}$$ simplifies to $$4\vec{AB} = \vec{AC}$$ and that should do it too, right?

Comment: @Alec: there [are] were two mistakes. The mixture of vectors and points makes it hard to read and error prone.

Comment: Yeah, I confused myself with the vector/point mixing too.